# Error installing the Google Assistant SDK for my Python Project

Tags: python, sdk, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-assist-api

I've been trying to install the google assistant SDK for my python project. My main goal is to have a python script which can send inputs to the google assistant and get a response back.
So far i have followed these steps [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python).
But I have run into some problems in [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample) step.

Firstly, i was not able to run `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev` to install the system dependencies in my python terminal.
so i just went along to the next steps anyways, and then ran into a problem while doing this command: `google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \ --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json`

after putting my path to the json in there i ran it and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 26, in <module>
    import requests
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Scripts\google-oauthlib-tool.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .interactive import get_user_credentials
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\interactive.py", line 27, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 65, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport.requests
  File "E:\Python Projects\ardbot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: The requests library is not installed from please install the requests package to use the requests transport.
```

i have installed the requests library in my virtual environment and it is also displayed in the list when i run `python -m pip freeze`
so i dont know what the problem is here.

Then i found a [github page](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-grpc) showing similar steps to do this and upon running this command: `pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool] google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_<client-id>.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`
with my path in it i got the follwing error:

```
Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --client-secrets
```

I dont know the reason behind these errors and just in case i will also provide the exact command i was running in both cases:

Google Official SDK page command:
`google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --client-secrets E:\Python Projects\ardbot\client_secret_437082373621-14k487nbddf6ha5ocvo13eu75r46jeib.apps.googleusercontent.com.json`

Github page command:
`pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool] google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets E:\Python Projects\ardbot\client_secret_437082373621-14k487nbddf6ha5ocvo13eu75r46jeib.apps.googleusercontent.com.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`

Please help me fix this problem as i have been trying for quite a long while till now.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried all the tutorials i could find online regarding this but none of them worked and no one else seems to have had the same problem.

Im expecting to make a python script that can send inputs to the google assistant and get an appropriate response back.

Thanks in advace!